# What mixture of liquid soap to water should I use for soil with high silicon content?

Tags: soil, soil-amendment

I want to use my Miracle-Gro spray attachment for spraying a soap solution on my lawn and plants since I have very high silicon in my soil.  we used [Naiad wetting agents](http://www.naiadcompany.com/products.html) on the golf course where I used to work, but that is on a much grander scale. Any ideas for a good mixture?

Comment: Why do you want to spray soap on your lawn?  What insect or pest problem is driving this?  If not insect control then what does the silicone do?  Pictures would help too....

Comment: high silicone content doesn't allow the soil to soak up water, i.e. the water will have a tendency to bead up on the surface.  i know i can use liquaid soap, or naiad to rectify this problem, but i've never tried it using a residential spray applicator

Answer (score 1):

There are a few solutions to your soil problem:

- top dressing twice a year with compost or similar with high amount of organic matter combined with watering slowly and deeply so the soil does not dry out.  This takes time to take effect, possibly several years
- surfactants are available for homeowners, usually at your local feed/agro products store.  Companies like [Aquatrol](http://aquatrols.com/turf/golf/products/soil-surfactants/revolution/?LOCALE=CA) have a number of products for golf courses and similar.
- dish soap at 5ml/litre can be applied. Do not use anti bacterial soap. Apply then water in to move it down into the soil. Do not repeat until you have seen the effect. This is only a short term solution. Apply once a month during the growing season.